# Maven project using EclipseLink for persistence runs on IDE, but fails when running from a built jar

Tags: java, maven, jpa, netbeans, eclipselink

I'm working on a maven project using eclipselink 2.7.8 for persistence. When I run it on my IDE (Netbeans 12.0) it works perfectly well, but when I attempt to run it from a built jar it doesn't.

This is the stack trace when I use the jar

```
Exception in thread "main" Local Exception Stack:
Exception [EclipseLink-30005] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.8.v20201217-ecdf3c32c4): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2cdf8d8a
Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.8.v20201217-ecdf3c32c4): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [MyPersistenceUnit] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException.exceptionSearchingForPersistenceResources(PersistenceUnitLoadingException.java:129)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:191)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:80)
        ...
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.8.v20201217-ecdf3c32c4): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [MyPersistenceUnit] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createPredeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2109)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2085)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.callPredeploy(JPAInitializer.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:107)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.8.v20201217-ecdf3c32c4): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [MyPersistenceUnit] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:233)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.hasEntity(MetadataProject.java:1441)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.objects.MetadataAnnotatedElement.isOneToMany(MetadataAnnotatedElement.java:693)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.ClassAccessor.buildAccessor(ClassAccessor.java:609)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.ClassAccessor.addAccessorFields(ClassAccessor.java:438)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.ClassAccessor.addAccessors(ClassAccessor.java:410)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.ClassAccessor.preProcess(ClassAccessor.java:1225)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EmbeddableAccessor.preProcess(EmbeddableAccessor.java:304)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processStage1(MetadataProject.java:1851)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.processORMMetadata(MetadataProcessor.java:579)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processORMetadata(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:629)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2006)
        ... 17 more
```

My persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
      <persistence-unit name="MyPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        ...
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:./bd/MyPersistenceUnit"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value=""/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>xxxx.xxxxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>Service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    
    <properties>      
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.8</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.194</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>          
            <groupId>org.fusesource.jansi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jansi</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>example</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>xxxx.xxxxx.service.demonstration.MainDemo</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        </configuration>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I suspect that it's something to do with how maven is building the jar, since it works fine on the IDE. I have tried to utilize different eclipselink versions too, but that didn't seem to help (I started this project using 2.5.2 but updated after I had problems due to incompatibilities with some Java 8 features)

**Edit:**

I am running the jar from Powershell, with the command "java -jar .\nameOfTheJar.jar"

Possibly relevant parts of my PATH variable:

`Path=C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;`

Comment: It's possible that your runtime environment outside of NetBeans is causing the problem rather than Maven. When running within the IDE NetBeans doesn't care about your `PATH` and `CLASSPATH` variables, but that is not true when running from the command line. You might want to verify that there is nothing in your `PATH` (or `CLASSPATH`) that is causing this issue, such as unexpected/unwanted versions of JDK and EclipseLink being specified. But if everything looks OK please update your question to show your settings for 'PATH' and 'CLASSPATH', and explain how the app is run from the command line.

Comment: Try removing those three `...\javapath` entries from your `PATH`, and then add the path to the JDK that your app is using within NetBeans. In my case it would be `C:\Java\jdk-11\bin;` but obviously yours will be different. Does the app run OK from a new Powershell window using the revised `PATH`? (Obviously revert your PATH after testing if appropriate.)